# How to find the number of trials given the success probability and variance?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

If X has a binomial distribution how do you find the number of trials given a success probability and the variance? I'm lost. Could I just divide the variance by the success probability?

Comment: I cannot parse the sentence “Number of trials given a success probability and the variance”. Can you copy exactly the problem, maybe with some math typesetting?

Answer (score 0):

The variance is $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$, so substitute $p$ and $\sigma^2$ into this and rearrange for $n$, i.e.
$$n=\frac{\sigma^2}{p(1-p)}.$$